# HTML contenteditable=true disorder/change the Table Row Structure unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

When I click on the edit button and try to edit the content of the  of the Email column.The HTML table structure changes weirdly.

This is my code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<script>
function deleteAction(){
 $("#fname").attr('contenteditable','true');
 $("#lname").attr('contenteditable','true');
 $("#email").attr('contenteditable','true');
}
</script>
<body>
<div class="container">            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="fname">John</td>
        <td id="lname">Doe</td>
        <td id="email">john@example.com</td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete" onclick="deleteAction()">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code snippet works well with SO inline code snippet runner. But You can see in the below picture that the same code works differently.

[image]

Can anyone fix the problem? And say me where I am going` wrong?

Comment: must be some other script thats modifying your dom. it works fine in jsfiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/eqxdvxms/

Comment: Doesn't work well in the SO inline snipper runner for me.

Answer (score 0):

After Debugging the code, I have come to know that the Grammarly extension in my chrome browser causes this problem. After disabling the extension, it works fine.